# How are the points computed in the ElGamal elliptic curve encryption algorithm?

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

I was looking at an example of the ElGamal encryption operation [here](https://lib.bsu.edu/beneficencepress/mathexchange/03-01/OMaley.pdf) (page 24), but I can't seem to understand why:
$$\beta = 3(10, 3) = (10, 8)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $a=5, b=4, (x_P,y_P) = (10,3) and p = 11$
Back to the page 22
calculate $s\equiv  (3x_P^2+a)(2y_P)^{-1} \mod p \equiv 5\mod 11$
calculate in $\mod p$: $2(10,3) = (5^2- 2\cdot 10,-3+5(10-5)) = (5,0) $
now add (5,0) to (10,3)  (use the rule in the page 21)
now we have $s\equiv (3-0)(10-5)^{-1}\mod p \equiv 5\mod p $
then $x_\beta \equiv (5^2 - 10 - 5)  \equiv    10\mod p$
and $y_\beta \equiv -3 + 5  (10 -10) \equiv 11-3 \equiv 8  \mod p$
Attention to use  $(5,0)$ instead of $(10,3)$ while calculating $y_\beta$.